# How to loop through Jmeter request?

Tags: jmeter

I have four requests

1. Login
2. ACtion1
3. Action2
4. Action3
   Here i want to repeat Action 1, action 2 and Action 3. which loop controller i have to use?

Comment: You're talking about the recursion, not about the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your scenario:

1. You can put your `Login` request under [Once-Only Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller) like:

   - Once Only Controller

     - Login
   - Action 1
   - Action 2
   - Action 3
2. You can put `Action*` requests under [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) like:

   - Login

     - Loop Controller (set desired number of loops)
     - Action 1
     - Action 2
     - Action 3
3. You can put `Login` request under [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) and use arbitrary condition to control when the "Login" will be executed

   - If Controller

     - Login
   - Action 1
   - Action 2
   - Action 3